# C# Entity Framework Property is (Sometimes) Null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I am having a very weird issue when using EF where sometimes property of a class is null and sometimes it is not. In this case *ParentType* is often null, when it should have a value

With the following code is DOES have a value:

```
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            checkedListBox_SubTypes.DataSource = context.Types.Where(x => x.ParentType != null && x.ParentType.TypeID == _selectedType.TypeID).ToList();
        }
```

However with this line of code, where i try to get the same object back out of a listbox, it ParentType becomes null

Below are my classes and DB diagram for how things are set up:

```
public class Type
{
    #region Fields
    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructor
    public Type()
    {

    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Properties
    public int? TypeID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public Type ParentType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Types this Type is associated with (Parent / Sub)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Object> Objects { get; set; }
    #endregion Properties
```

Context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        //Set Many-To-Many relationship Mapping between Object & Type
        modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectType>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Objects)
            .WithMany(x => x.Types)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ObjectType")
            .MapLeftKey("TypeID")
            .MapRightKey("ObjectNumber"));


        //Set One-To-Many relationship Mapping between Type &(Parent)Type
        modelBuilder.Entity<Type>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Types)
            .WithOptional(x => x.ParentType)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Type")
            .MapKey("ParentTypeID"));

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data for those records where you are getting this property as NULL ?

Comment: Most probably lazy loading related. Have you tried `Include`? Don't be fooled by the `Where` clause, it doesn't deal with objects at all.

Comment: @Shyju Yes, I am absolutely positive I have data for those records

Comment: @IvanStoev I am not very familiar with using Include, can you give an example of how I would use it in this context? and what do you mean by "Where" not dealing with objects?

Comment: `ParentMatterType` isn't virtual, so it doesn't load lazily.

Comment: @GertArnold whether i set it as virtual or not does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Michael Take a look at this [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Add an `Include` to it in your `OnModelBinding`. Like others have said, it's lazy loading. Follow the pattern you're using with the collections.

Comment: @ragerory What do you mean add an include in the OnModelBinding,  and following the pattern with collections? you mean set ParentMatterType to virtual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that in your first code fragment `ParentMatterType` is null too. Let's change it a little bit:

```
using (LitTrackContext context = new LitTrackContext())
{
    var types = context.MatterTypes
                       .Where(x => x.ParentMatterType != null 
                                && x.ParentMatterType.MatterTypeID == _selectedMatterType.MatterTypeID)
                       .ToList();
    checkedListBox_MatterSubTypes.DataSource = types;
}
```

If you inspect `types` in the debugger you'll see that there are no `ParentMatterType`s in there. That's because the property isn't `virtual`, so it isn't loaded lazily (which would happen if you inspect it in the debugger).

Even if you make the property `virtual` you won't be able to see its content later, because the context is disposed immediately (which is good, by the way). If you would try to access `ParentMatterType` afterwards, EF would throw an exception.

You should instead `Include` the property in your query, by changing the first part:

```
var types = context.MatterTypes.Include(m => m.ParentMatterType)
...
```

Comment: Spot on Solution. This makes it work, and explanation was good :)

My only question is, why do I have to "Include" ParentMatterType but not "Include" properties like MatterTypeName or MatterTypeID. Is it because of complex types vs primitive Types, or does it have to do with being a navigation property?

Comment: Yes, it's because it's a navigation property.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue retrieving datasources once it has been bounded onto a control, in my case DataGrids. I have never figured out why this is or investigated further. To work around this problem, what I would normally do is keep a reference of the object in a Session or ViewState, or a class level variable just before I assign it to the control. So later on, I would still have a reference to the object If I need so.

Comment: Ah. I see what you did there. Create a reference to the datasource first like I said in my previous post, say originalList. Then find the item from there:

foreach(var item in checkListBox.SelectedItems)
{
var smt = originalList.Where(m => m.MatterNumber ==   item.value).FirstOrDefault();
}

Comment: Don't do this. ViewState is not reliable when navigating between pages, and if you're going to store something in session, don't store an entire object like he is above. Also, the OP has tagged this as `winforms`, which is stateless and has no concept of either session or viewstate.